# How to work with form elements in typescript

Tags: javascript, casting, typescript

I'd like to access form elements via `myForm.elements`, and then access each element by it's name, for example, `myForm.elements.month`. Typescript doesn't like this b/c it doesn't know that `form.elements` contains a property of `month`. I thought, let's create an interface! So I did, (see code below), but I'm getting this typescript error: `Neither type 'HTMLCollection' nor type 'FormElements' is assignable to the other`

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
interface FormElements {
    day: HTMLInputElement;
    month: HTMLInputElement;
    year: HTMLInputElement;
}

class BirthdateInput {
    constructor(form: HTMLFormElement) {
        var elements: FormElements = <FormElements> form.elements; // error here

        this.day = elements.day;
        this.month = elements.month;
        this.year = elements.year;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to better cast my `form.elements` object so typescript won't complain?

Answer (score 6):

Best way would be to write it like this:

```
// Note 'extends' clause here
interface FormElements extends HTMLFormElement {
    day: HTMLInputElement;
    month: HTMLInputElement;
    year: HTMLInputElement;
}

class BirthdateInput {
    constructor(form: HTMLFormElement) {
        var elements: FormElements = <FormElements> form.elements; // OK
        // ...
```

Comment: `FormElements` actually corresponds to form.elements, not the form itself, so it's better to extend from `HTMLCollection`, or possibly `HTMLFormControlsCollection` than `HTMLFormElement`. But the `extends` aspect is correct.

Comment: if you are going to do this in `.tsx`. You have to use `as` keyword instead. 
`var elements: FormElements = form.elements as FormElements;`

Answer (score 5):

Turns out adding an `extends` clause fixes it:

```
interface FormElements extends HTMLCollection {
    day: HTMLInputElement;
    month: HTMLInputElement;
    year: HTMLInputElement;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Origin answer

Create an interface extending `HTMLFormControlsCollection` or `HTMLCollection` and add there your inputs

```
interface FormElements extends HTMLFormControlsCollection {
    day: HTMLInputElement
    month: HTMLInputElement
    year: HTMLInputElement
}
```

Eventually, for example, getting this

```
interface FormElements extends HTMLFormControlsCollection {
    day: HTMLInputElement
    month: HTMLInputElement
    year: HTMLInputElement
}
function onSearch(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const elements = event.currentTarget.elements as FormElements

    // ...
  }
```

### However

You can create a helper so you don't need to write an interface for each form every time

```
type FormElements<U extends string> = HTMLFormControlsCollection & Record<U, HTMLInputElement>
```

And use it like this

```
const elements = event.currentTarget.elements as FormElements<"id" | "name" | "type" | "amount">
```

Eventually, for example, getting this

```
function onSearch(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const elements = event.currentTarget.elements as FormElements<"id" | "name" | "type" | "amount">

    // ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether right or wrong, I have found that you can also do something like this:

```
interface FormElements {
    day: HTMLInputElement;
    month: HTMLInputElement;
    year: HTMLInputElement;
}

class BirthdateInput {
    constructor(form: HTMLFormElement) {
        var elements: FormElements = <FormElements>(<any> form.elements); 

        this.day = elements.day;
        this.month = elements.month;
        this.year = elements.year;
    }
}
```